# Currently, in Django-notification, everytime I send a notification, it sends the email in plain text

Tags: python, html, css, django, notifications

Is there a way to customize the HTML and send a notification email in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adjust your template, e.g.

- https://github.com/pinax/django-notification/blob/master/notification/templates/notification/email_body.txt

or add an extra template, e.g. `email_body.html`. For that you'll have to adjust `models.py` starting, e.g. here:

- https://github.com/pinax/django-notification/blob/master/notification/models.py#L311

Comment: If I adjust my template, can I add HTML tags to it?

Comment: This pull request shows how to do it: https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/pull/40/files (and I fixed the links in the answer)